# Erev Rosh Hashana 5781 - mikvah via 'tes kavin'

Tags: halacha-theory, mikvah-ritual-bath, high-holidays

Given the nature of the pandemic Rav Hershel Schachter amongst many others have advised against going to the mikvah (see [here](http://web.colby.edu/coronaguidance/files/2020/08/Schachter-matters-related-to-Rosh-Hashanah-and-Yom-Kippur.pdf)) in letter dalet:

[image]

Instead people are being advise to 'dip' via a shower using the principle of ''Tes Kavin'. Can anyone explain more about this principle - and how long in the shower does one need to spend to be considered like dipping in a mikvah? Presumably there would be a difference if one has a power-shower (i.e. since it comes out more powerfully and quicker one could spend less time) vs an older shower which is nowhere near as strong and thus would require longer time under the shower?

Comment: If you want to measure your particular shower's flow rate, get a bucket and a stopwatch.

Comment: How much would the water equate to in modern day measures?

Comment: There are 4 log in a kav